# Sql Select top 2 , bottom 2 and 6 random records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to select top 2 , bottom 2 and 6 random (not in Top 2 and Bottom 2) records of the table  using one SQL select query?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS SQL 2005/2008:

```
with cte
as
(
    select 
        row_number() over (order by name) RowNumber, 
        row_number() over (order by newid()) RandomOrder,
        count(*) over() Total,
        *
    from sys.tables
)
select *
from cte
where RowNumber <= 2 or Total - RowNumber + 1 <= 2
union all
select *
from
(
    select top 6 *
    from cte 
    where RowNumber > 2 and Total - RowNumber > 2
    order by RandomOrder
) tt
```

Replace `sys.tables` with your table name and alter `order by name` to specify order condition for top 2 and bottom 2.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a single select statment, but it can be executed in one call:

```
/* Top 2 - change order by to get the 'proper' top 2 */
SELECT * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
/* Random 6.. You may want to add a WHERE and random data to get the random 6 */
/* Old Statement before edit - SELECT * from table LIMIT 6 */

SELECT * from table t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) AS top ON top.id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) AS bottom ON bottom.id = t.id
WHERE ISNULL(top.id ) AND ISNULL(bottom.id)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 6

UNION ALL
/* Bottom 2 - change order by to get the 'proper' bottom 2 */
SELECT * from table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2
```

Something along those lines. Basically the `UNION All` is the trick.

Comment: Wrong. The question specifies the random 6 are NOT to be from the top or bottom 2

Comment: You could also use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` in case your bottom/top/random values overlap, i.e. with `UNION` you will never get duplicate rows

Comment: I don't have where clause and I don't want to pass random data

Comment: The two subselects in the intermediate SELECT are absolutely identical. I understand, they should be ordered opposite to each other, unless I've missed something. Also I would expect the 'top 2' SELECT to sort rows in ascending order, and the 'bottom 2' one to do so in the opposite direction... Still, there's more point in being consistent throughout the entire query, so if your 'top 2' means 'the last 2', it's fine by me as long as 'the bottom 2' means 'the first 2'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "order" is by the id column:

```
select * from (select id, id from my_table order by id limit 2) t1
union
select * from (select id, id from my_table where id not in (
    select * from (select id from my_table order by id asc limit 2) t22
    union
    select * from (select id from my_table order by id desc limit 2 ) t23)
order by rand()
limit 6) t2
union
select * from (select id, id from my_table order by id desc limit 2) t3
```

EDIT: Fixed syntax and tested query - it works

Comment: The random shouldn't include the 2 top and 2 bottom ones.

Comment: @arlen: There is no "sql 2005". There is "SQL Server 2005".